# Invalid tld file: aef_structure.tld

Tags: java, jar, tld

While trying to [install agilefant](https://github.com/Agilefant/agilefant/wiki/Agilefant-installation-guide) I was able to deploy the war and while trying to login, I am getting the following error

> ```
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Invalid tld file: "/WEB-INF/tags/structure/../../tlds/aef_structure.tld", see JSP 2.2 specification section 7.3.1 for more details
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
> org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:347)
> ```

Are there any supporting libraries or jars would be allow me to identify this tld file?

Comment: What did you learn when you went to section 7.3.1 of the JSP 2.2 specification?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in this [link](https://github.com/Agilefant/agilefant/pull/42/commits/68152989a3889346835e7bcf6e5c11076a3a9ff5)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The TLD file relative path in JSP page as reference is declared incorrectly and caused this issue.